# Running a function from within preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php

I have a website which employs a PHP script to load some data from an HTML file and insert it in a link. So far it works perfectly:

```
$html = preg_replace('/(\d+):(\d+),/', '<a href="index.php?par1=$1&amp;par2=$2">$1&#58;$2</a>,', $html);
```

Now I want to upgrade it to insert tooltips in the links. The data is loaded from a database and I have a special function `loadTooltip($param1, $param2)` that does the job. The problem is how to call the function from within `preg_replace()`. This is the code that I have but it doesn't run the data simply showing the name of the function with the parameters. This is the code:

```
$html = preg_replace('/(\d+):(\d+),/', '<a href="index.php?par1=$1&amp;par2=$2" titel="loadTooltip($1, $2)">$1&#58;$2</a>,', $html);
```

So, how can I make it run?

Comment: check [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for the task.

You might have to edit the output string of your function a bit.